# What's up with the ranking in stage two in Divergent?

Tags: divergent

They start out with 11 Dauntless-born initiates and 9 transfers. Now,

> Two of each get cut after stage one.

However, in the stage two rankings, there is this:

> My name is in the first slot. Heads turn in my direction. I follow the list down. Christina and Will are seventh and ninth, respectively.

How could this be if they were ranked separately?

**Edit:** Here's a quote which shows that they were ranked separately in stage two.

> ”I take it your ranks were good,” I say to Lynn.
> She nods, “Uriah’s second.  I’m first.  Marlene’s fourth.”

Comment: AFAIR only stage one had separate rankings and even then there was no rule that two of each should be cut, that's simply what happened.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I didn't say there was a rule, but that *is* what happened. If you look at the quotes in the link I gave, you'll see that they *were* ranked separately.

Comment: @CodesInChaos see edit.

Comment: I believe the first and third linked quote refer to stage 1 with seperate rankings and the second quote to stage 2 with joint rankings. Will check the book when I'm at home.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the third quote is a few pages *after* the second one, so... no.

Comment: I thought the same thing, and just attributed it to author error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I purchased my copy of Divergent from the Australian iBookstore recently (April/May 2014) and my text is *different* to what's quoted in the question; my copy says:

> My name is in the first slot.
> Heads turn in my direction. I follow the list down. Christina and Will are **fourth** and **sixth** [emphasis mine], respectively. Peter is second…

This tells me the other answerers are, in fact, correct in their conclusion that listing Christina and Will's place as seventh and ninth was an author error.

Comment: Don't you just love those authors who put consistency above canonity?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed it too.  IMO it's an editing blunder.  After stage 1, Edward and Myra left leaving only 7 transfer initiates.  Will and Christina were ranked 7th and 9th AFTER stage 2, with Al ranked "last" (which would be after 9th?), which makes no sense unless the Dauntless-born initiates were ranked with the transfers, AND the the Dauntless-born ranked lower than the top transfers - highly unlikely.  Lynn's quote about ranking first and Uriah second was a few pages later at the beginning of stage 3, pretty sure the ranks didn't change between the end of stage 2 and the beginning of stage 3.  So yes, they were ranked separately and this was a continuity blunder.

Still an excellent first book by a talented young author.  So talented that I only noticed this inconsistency on my third (or maybe fourth) reading.

Answer (score -1):

I googled wondering the exact same thing. They WERE ranked separately. Will is mentioned as being 9th and later it states she searched for Al and finds him in "the last spot" (which would be 9th). I read this several times, confused especially when Peter (ranked 2nd) tells Will she will make him factionless.  Then later she runs off to see Uriah shoot a muffin and finds out he is ranked 2nd.  So they were definitely separate. I'm guessing this is a disappointing poor edit.

Comment: You're not really adding anything except confirming my question.